# Parse MySQL queries, including JOINs

Tags: javascript, mysql, parsing

Is there an already built tool in PHP or Javascript that parses MySQL queries, **including JOINs**.

What I need as a result is simply two arrays:

The first is an array of the Query Result fields. (result[]) 
The second is an array of the Query Parameters. (params[])

Example:

```
    Select PersonID,firstName,lastName,countryName
    FROM Person 
    LEFT JOIN Country ON Person.countryID=Country.countryID

    Where firstName="Jonathan" and countryName="Canada"
```

Would result in the following:

```
result=['PersonID','firstName','lastName','countryName'];

params=['firstName','countryName'];
```

Comment: I guess if you are using PHP PDO Prepared statements you could get each of the applied attributes which could be the requested columns and where parameters. What would you want to do with this?

Comment: I need for automating Ajax-like tasks based on JSON structures.

Answer (score 1):

This library would probably help you as it parse the query and return every information as an array: [php-sql-parser](https://github.com/soundintheory/php-sql-parser)

Answer (score 1):

There is also a javascript library: [javascript sql parser](https://github.com/forward/sql-parser)

The parser returns an object that contains all the information about the sql query. it supports for now only select statement.